# Hover jquery после добавления элементов

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, события, hover

Есть список ul. В нём блоки li. При первой загрузке страницы, при помощи jquery в список ul добавляются блоки li методом `append()` (Изначально ul пустой).
Далее при прокрутке страницы добавляются ещё элементы в конец ul. 
При наведении на li блок появляется скрытый блок. Для отображения я применяю событие hover().

Проблема в том что это событие срабатывает для элементов которые были добавлены при первой загрузке страницы, а для элементов которые добавляются при прокрутке страницы это событие не срабатывает. Из-за чего это может быть? 
Добавлю. Так же есть `hover` который прописан при помощи css и он работает.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var index = 0,
    count = 15,
    append = false,
    curr_append = 0;

  function appendBlock(count) {
    for (var i = 0; i <= count; i++) {
      $('ul.blocks').append(
        '<li class = "block-' + index + '">' +
        '<a> Block </a>' +
        '<div class="block-info"></div>' +
        '</li>'
      );
      index++;
    }
    append = true;
  };

  if (!append) {
    appendBlock(count);
  }

  $(window).scroll(function() {

    fromBottom = document.body.scrollHeight - scrollY;

    if (fromBottom <= 800 && curr_append <= 6) {
      appendBlock(count);
      curr_append++;
    }
  });
  
  var curr_block;
  $('li[class^="block-"]').hover(function() {

    var start = "block-";

    var curr_block_index = getIndex($(this), start);

    curr_block = $('li.block-' + curr_block_index);

    curr_block.find('div.block-info').stop().slideDown(300);

  }, function() {
    curr_block.find('div.block-info').stop().slideUp(300);
  });

  $("body").on("hover", "ul.blocks li.block-0", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("Hover");
            console.log("hover");
     });

  function getIndex(element, start) {

    var tmp = element.attr('class').split(' ');

    for (var i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++) {
      if (tmp[i].startsWith(start)) {
        var result = tmp[i];
      }
    }

    var index = result.substr(result.lastIndexOf('-') + 1, result.lengh);

    return index;
  };
});
```

```css
ul.blocks {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px !important;
}
li[class^='block-'] {
  width: 200px;
  height: 170px;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  visibility: visible;
  background: #EFEFEF;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 5px 10px 5px !important;
  box-shadow: 0 0px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) !important;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) !important;
  -o-box-shadow: 0 0px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) !important;
  -webkit-transition: .4s ease-out !important;
  -moz-transition: .4s ease-out !important;
  -ms-transition: .4s ease-out !important;
  -o-transition: .4s ease-out !important;
  transition: .4s ease-out !important;
}
li[class^='block-']:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) !important;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) !important;
  -o-box-shadow: 0 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) !important;
}
li[class^='block-'] a {
  line-height: 170px;
  color: #333;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
div.block-info {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 55%;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(224, 224, 224, 0.5);
}
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="blocks clearfix">

</ul>
```

Comment: пример кода покажи пожалуйста?

Comment: @stas0k кода чего именно? наведения или добавления?

Comment: я имел ввиду сюда код свой загрузи чтобы можно было воспроизвести. или ссылку на твой пример. А вообще вроде ниже ответили уже

Comment: @stas0k добавил в шапку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот здесь обработчик на добавленные объекты работает,дальше уже делайте как Вам необходимо

```
$("body").on("mouseover", "ul li", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $(this).text("Работает")

 });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8fgdhsg8/2/

Comment: Спасибо. тоже решение.

Comment: Но на рабочем сайте не работает.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте обработчик сделать так

```
     $("body").on("hover", "ul li", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            // действия
     });
```

Comment: теперь блок не появляется вовсе.

Comment: Так выложите свой код.

Comment: добавил в шапку

Answer (score 0):

Решение: Перед добавлением новых элементов убирать обработчик событий `hover` и после добавления создавать новый обработчик событий.